# How to set progress bar while we are uploading a file using Retrofit. I need progress bar counting 100

Tags: java, android

```
public class ProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {


    private File mFile;
    private String mPath;
    private UploadCallbacks mListener;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    public interface UploadCallbacks {
        void onProgressUpdate(int percentage);
        void onError();
        void onFinish();
    }

    public ProgressRequestBody(File file,UploadCallbacks listener) {
        mFile = file;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        // i want to upload only images
        return MediaType.parse("image/*");
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() throws IOException {
        return mFile.length();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {

        Source source = null;
        try {
            source = Okio.source(mFile);
            long total = 0;
            long read;

            while ((read = source.read(sink.buffer(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {

                total += read;
                sink.flush();
                mListener.onProgressUpdate((int)(100 * total / mFile.length()));

            }
        } finally {
            Util.closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }
```

---

In the above code progress bar appears twice when we upload a single file.
Means internally writing the file first and uploading happening second time.
So it's showing two progress bars. How can we avoid that first progress bar shows?

Comment: i dont see any `ProgressBar` in your code

Comment: i think you refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551/5110595) link but  in your code there is no progress bar.

Comment: mListener.onProgressUpdate((int)(100 * total / mFile.length()));    It showing the progress bar

Comment: you cant a progressbar that counts 0 to 100? bit of pointless. What if the upload takes 275 counts?

Comment: @HemantParmar It showing two progress bar for the same file .

Comment: @Stultuske Above code showing count from 1-100 . But twice for the same file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)

Comment: @saneesh for twice progress bar have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867216/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar Thanks alot

Comment: @saneesh is that link is useful ??

Comment: @HemantParmar  Yeah nice tricky way